# When entering data that is automatically added to the sql database, the error IndexError: list index out of range is written

Tags: python, kivy

```
def add_subject_to_timetable(self, instance):
    day_input = self.add_subject_menu.content.children[0].children[0].children[2]
    day = None
    for child in day_input.children:
        if hasattr(child, 'text'):
            day = child.text.strip()
            break
    days_of_week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
    if day in days_of_week:
        time_input = self.add_subject_menu.content.children[0].children[0].children[4].children[0]
        subject_input = self.add_subject_menu.content.children[0].children[0].children[6].children[0]
        time = time_input.text.strip()
        subject = subject_input.text.strip()
        if time and subject:
            class_id = 1
            self.db.execute("INSERT INTO timetable (day, time, class_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                            (day, time, class_id))
            self.db.commit()
            self.add_subject_menu.dismiss()
        else:
            self.show_popup('Error', 'Enter time and subject')
    else:
        self.show_popup(Error', 'Invalid day of week')
```

part of the code that is responsible for this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeXoZ.png)
this error comes up:
in add_subject_to_timetable
day_input = self.add_subject_menu.content.children[0].children[0].children[2]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

it should turn out that when you enter certain data such as: subject, day of the week, time, they are added to the database